# Zoom and pan canvas drawing in android

Tags: android, canvas

I want to zoom and pan a canvas in android. Canvas has interactive objects, users can touch point and drag them. I want to add the zoom in feature and panning feature while the canvas is zoomed without affecting the object interactions by the users.

I used scalegesturedetector, however I cant zoom the desired location and pan as well.

Is there a sample code for this? I couldn't find any sample which implement object interactions and zoom/pan together.

Thanks